# Possible to automatically generate a custom composite annotation for use on a Java Entity field containing a populated @Column annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, annotation-processing

Due to a bug in `liquibase-hibernate` Java Bean Validation constraint annotations (e.g `@NotNull`, `@Size`) on Java Entity classes are not being mapped to any generated Liquibase changelogs:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/301

I'm wondering is it possible to generate a custom composite annotation during the compilation process?

The idea is that a new annotation named `@CustomColumnId` would be generated automatically based on the presence of the `@MyCustomAnnotation` annotation on the `ItemDTO` class, the same being done for all fields in the class.

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@MyCustomAnnotation
public class ItemDTO {

    @NotNull
    public Long id;
}
```

The generated annotation would also contain the JPA `@Column` annotation and automatically set the `nullable` attribute based on the presence of `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` on `id` and the `name` attribute to the field name.

Something generated like:

```java
@Generated
class Item_Constraints {
    
    @jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull()
    @jakarta.persistence.Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @jakarta.validation.Constraint(validatedBy = {})
    public @interface CustomColumnId {
        String message() default "{my.package.Item_Constraints.message}";
        Class<?>[] groups() default { };
        Class<? extends jakarta.validation.Payload>[] payload() default { };
    }

}
```

Then the developer can update their Java Entity to be:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class ItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @CustomColumnId
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Essentially preventing developers from having to duplicate their constraint information across both DTO and Java Entity.

Original Java Entity:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class ItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```